# boot IBM p series 650 from 3580-L23 LTO-2 tape

Tags: aix, ibm, tape, tapedrive, lto

We have a p series 650 that has a dds4 tape drive built-in. In the past, recover has been as simple as putting a mksysb tape into the drive and booting the machine. During boot, the machine detects that a tape is in the drive and goes into the restore setup. This all works well.

We are trying to upgrade to a bigger, faster tape. The drive we are moving to is a 3580-L23 drive, which uses LTO-2 tapes. We are able to run the mksysb command and write the tape successfully. We've also done a file listing from the tape and verified that the root vg looks good.

The last hurdle for us is getting the system to boot from the 3580. The problem is that when the system boots, it doesn't boot from the 3580 - it skips straight to the internal hard drives. We've tried looking around in the AIX bootlist, but it doesn't list any tape drive of any kind, including the dd4 drive. At this point we're pretty sure there's some config in the IPL that we're just missing that lists the boot order, but we can't seem to find it.

Comment: Nobody seems to have any comments, so here is a link to a thread I made on a different site: http://unix.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/ibm-aix-l/boot-ibm-p-series-650-from-3580l23-lto2-tape-4713827

Comment: If that site happens to disappear in the future, the end result was that I gave up trying to figure out why the system was attempting to boot from the dds4 tape and changed the bootlist like this: `>bootlist -m normal rmt0 rmt1 hdisk2 hdisk3`

Comment: Isn't much easier just to boot into SMS and select from where do you want to boot? chsysstate -m pserver -r lpar -o on -f profilename -n lparname -b sms (IIRC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that site happens to disappear in the future, the end result was that I gave up trying to figure out why the system was attempting to boot from the dds4 tape and changed the bootlist like this: >bootlist -m normal rmt0 rmt1 hdisk2 hdisk3